# Can't auto complete in XML files in Android Studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

Is there any way to auto complete in XML files in Android studio? Eg: When I start typing RelativeLayout, I want Android studio to recognize it and give me a bare-bones prototype that I can just fill in. Is there any way to enable this?

I checked other answers and my power save mode is off and I'm not using any external libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I finally notice it was only the current XML file I was working on which had the issue, and inside a relative layout that have been defined from the WYSWYG editor. Don't know why exactly, rewrite it and everything fine again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `File -> Invalidate Cache/Restart`. That did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot use autocomplete in any xml, the working solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries).
However, if the problem is only with some xml files, you may have used custom views in them, where autocomplete will not work. The workaround is to temporarily change your custom view's name to its original android view and use autocomplete inside, and then revert the view to its custom name.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these from preferences.

```
Settings(Preferences in mac)->Editor->Code Completion
```

Please double check power safe mode too. it should be off

Comment: Yep did both of those things before asking here. I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: I have the same issue, none of the tips and other answers solved it. If I start typing then the suggestions will start appearing.

Answer (score 0):

reset your android studio (or) find .AndroidStudio(version) in your system in that config will be there delete it and reopen android studio it will ask default settings