# Android Studio - XML Editor autocomplete not working with support libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

I just started using the new android.support.design library. When using any of the widgets inside the XML editor I stop getting the XML autocomplete suggestions!

For example,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/header_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/header_root"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

None of the tags will show the autocomplete popup, like when I start typing "android:i" no popup appears, the only suggestion I get is shown in the following picture.

[image]

I have tried cleaning my project, restarting the pc, restarting Android Studio.. nothing is working!

Comment: same here, xml auto complete not working when using custom library

Comment: Have you resolved this issue yet?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet. The support library still doesn't populate.

Comment: It would be so nice if Google gave us a working editor before shutting down Eclipse!

Comment: Related bug report: [Issue 61844: Autocomplete stopped working](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61844). Please star so that they fix the issue.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier After about 4 years now, they've closed the issue as "Won't fix (obsolete)"! Well, there goes all our stars!  xP

Comment: @Varun haha at least we can gladly say today's AS is leaps and bounds ahead of the first versions back in the day

Answer (score 138, accepted):

I have tried a lot of things (restart Android Studio, PC, Invalidate Caches, Power Saver mode,...).

Finally, deleting the **.idea** folder and all **.iml** files from the project, restarting Android Studio, and rebuilding Gradle did the trick. Autocomplete in XML support library is working again.

Checking out files from Version Control or copying all the source files in a new project would do the trick as well.

Comment: The common answers for questions about this, didn't work for me either. I was starting to think I'd just have to put up with it, until I found your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Need to open the project by browsing to the physical folder itself. Project entry on Android Studio startup screen didn't work for me.

Comment: This method worked for me, but after a few days of coding it seems to always come back. Anyone know if there is a way to find out how it is becoming corrupted?

Comment: Same here... in the  latest realease of SDK 23, buildTools and support libraries, I saw in the release log, that they fixed some issues around that, lets hope it fixed... :)

Comment: not working.
Please use this solution its working fine https://stackoverflow.com/a/54007742/4373587

Comment: didnt work in my case + messed up my project structure

Comment: Where are .iml  files?

Answer (score 147):

If `NONE` of the above answers worked, ...

Just navigate to your android studio installation directory, i.e,

```
yourDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.3/system
```

and **DELETE THE CACHE FOLDER** ( first close android studio, if its running ).

Then start Android Studio again. **Done**.

P.S *I am using android studio 4.0*

Comment: for me, removing the whole .AndroidStudio3.3 folder did the trick. I think it goofed up during the import process.

Comment: Works for Android 3.6 as well.

Comment: Thank you so much @Santanu Sur, It's working for Android 3.6.2 as well.

Comment: C:\Users\your_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.6\system

Comment: Where is this for macos?

Answer (score 131):

The answer for me was to switch to lower sdk when compiling project, I think this is platform problem. I was using sdk 33.

Change in build.gradle

```
compileSdk=32
```

Edit: It seems that it is also fixed in newest Android Studio version

Comment: Just update Android Studio to Dolphin version. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/235792434

Comment: This works fine, but also downgrade the `targetSdkVersion` to same version with `compileSdk`

Comment: Cool it worked instantly! Can you please explain the reason?

Answer (score 38):

I got my autocomplete suggestions back by invalidating Caches and restarting.

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart

Comment: It seems that invalidate caches/restart solves all the problems in Android Studio!

Answer (score 32):

This same problem appeared in version **3.2.** . The solution for that is

```
Close Android Studio
Go to C:\Users\UserName\.android and rename the build-cache folder to build-cache.bak

Go to C:\Users\UserName\.AndroidStudio3.2\system and rename these folders

caches to caches.bak

compiler to compiler.bak

compile-server to compile-server.bak

conversion to conversion.bak

external_build_system to external_build_system.bak

frameworks to frameworks.bak

gradle to gradle.bak

resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache.bak

Open the Android Studio and open your project again.
```

Comment: It actually works. We just need to start indexing for android studio again. Like resetting index

Comment: works like a charm!! Thanks, android studio resetting its index

Comment: worked on android studio 4. invalidating, restarting and deleting caches did not work for me and after a while I faced the problem again. but this worked. tnx.

Answer (score 25):

If NONE of the above worked ...

Just navigate to your android studio installation directory, i.e,

**yourDrive:/.AndroidStudio3.4/system**

first close android studio, if its running.

then delete the cache folder in system

Then start Android Studio again. Done.

i am using android studio 3.4

Comment: Really helpful, but first try following options and then try above one.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It is now even showing resources correctly as suggestions

Comment: I tried everything but didn't get anything working. This answer appears as the savior.

Answer (score 9):

I try to downgrade the "Compile SDK Version" from 29 to 28 and it's works good

Comment: Targeting sdk version 28 is not supporting on google play store any more. Even those apps targeting 29 won't be accepted on google play store after 31st August 2021.

Answer (score 9):

If u have updated ur compileSdkVersion 33. Decrease it.
It works in my case

```
compileSdkVersion 32
 targetSdkVersion 32
```

Answer (score 6):

If you use compileSdkVersion 33, upgrade your Android Studio to Dolphin. It worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

The [Santanu Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304838/5064470) answer works for me! But in Windows I found these folders in **%USERNAME%/.AndroidStudio3.4** or **%USERNAME%/.AndroidStudio3.3**

I deleted these two folders and it worked well finally.

Comment: Worked perfectly but delete only caches folder under [Users > Username > .AndroidStudio3.5 > system].

Answer (score 3):

Deleting Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio* folder and Invalidate Cache after that helped me. All other options didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

*A few years too late, but I wanted to submit an answer to this that I figured out and worked for me. It was very quick and didnt require a lot of reconfiguration as some of other answers on here had, so I thought I'd add it.*

**Solution**

Comment the gradle dependencies for xml attributes, sync the project, and then un-comment them and sync it again. For me, resyncing these three with and then without the comments was enough to get them to start coming up again.

```
//implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
//implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

And don't worry if your build fails after the first step, it should if you already have any of those attributes in your project. Another note, the attributes that I had previously put in (without the autocomplete before the resync) needed to be re-inputted for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

I got in a situation where only the `EditText` tag was broken. I've deleted the **.idea** folder and all **.iml**, invalidated the cache and restarted... What actually worked was to erase the tag and type it again. Really Odd.

Comment: why its important to delete .idea folder whats the logic

Comment: so, we had to check whether the problem exists in all places or in a single file/ in specific files, then should check the broken layout code

Answer (score 2):

I too faced this issue and this was only happening on an imported module class. Tried everything like deleting `.idea` folder, `power saver mode`, `invalidate cache and restart`, etc.

Finally updating `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` of the module to match with the app module fixed the issue.

In my case I was using:

```
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
```

Answer (score 2):

Tried everything like deleting .idea folder, power saver mode, deleting cache folder under user/.android , invalidate cache and restart, etc nothing worked.

Setting `compileSdkVersion 31` (latest till date) worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

As this just happened to me, working with Android Studio Chipmunk Patch 2. and nothing of the above answers worked so **targeting SDK version number 33 causing this error lowering it  solved the issue**

```
    defaultConfig {
            targetSdkVersion = 30
            compileSdkVersion = 30 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried all, Invalidate Cache, Restart, Clean, and rebuild the project. Downgrading from SDK 33 to 30 also I did after searching. Nothing worked.

In the end, I updated my Android Studio from Chipmunk to Dolphin. Everything is sorted now.

So the final conclusion that worked for me is: Update the Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

In my case [Code Completion](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html) suggestions were not appearing because Gradle dependency was missing in my application's module.

I was using `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` in my XML layout, but I have not added Design Support Library `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` Gradle dependency in my application module.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having this problem in November 2018 with Android Studio 3.2.1, you should try downgrading it to 3.1.4.

With 3.2.1 i tried every of this answers and didn't work, but after i downgraded to 3.1.4 and did the *Invalidate Caches / Restart* it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with **Invalid caches/restart** option but it didn't work for me.
For Android Studio **3>** versions check following first:

```
compileSdkVersion
targetSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion
```

Set these 3 to the latest version and then try to sync the project and clean, ReBuild once. It will work and show the XML editor autocomplete options.

Comment: Yes. Work for me with androidx library

Answer (score 1):

Delete the complete folder ` of the android studio and then restarting it. Solve the problem

> driveLocation:/.AndroidStudio3.3

`.AndroidStudio3.3` may be different in your case

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to check `power mode` in the android studio. Go to `File > Power mode` and check it's on or off. 
If it is on, You also will not get any suggestions. To get suggestions, It must be off.

If it doesn't work for you then you should reset your Android studio which will set the default configuration for you. 
For that, find out `.AndroidStudioBeta` or `.AndroidStudio` folder and delete those and restart the android studio. Generally, you will get this folder into `users\[user name]\.AndroidStudio3.3`.

Let me know if it helps you then. Happy coding..!

Answer (score 1):

In my android studio is dolphin(old version)  and I have set  compileSdkVersion 33 so this issue come then i  compileSdkVersion 32 set.  It's working fine.
So decrease  compileSdkVersion version.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by deleting '.androidStudioPreview1.X' in my home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I too got in a situation where only the EditText tag was broken. The solution was found in Setting > Editor >General > Auto Import where Edit Text was listed as excluded from auto completion. Remove that by select and click Minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart

and turn of power save mode it does works

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to make a zip folder of the project and change its path.(Relocate this project than open it).
This will do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

Check 5 ways:

1. Restart Android Studio
2. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
3. File -> turn of power save mode and restart Android Studio
4. Delete .idea folder. Search for *.iml files and delete all those and use way number 2

Answer (score 0):

Change to an **older version** in **build.gradle(Module: app)** -Make sure is the one under Gradle Script and it is NOT build.gradle(Project: yourproject). After getting  XML autocomplete suggestions change to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I tried to autocomplete on an xml layout file inside `res/xml`. Autocomplete does not work there for layout files. Moving the xml file to `res/layout` made autocomplete work again.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried waiting for 10 seconds and the auto-complete suggestions appeared(Using Android Studio 4.2) , it seems that the xml just takes some time to resolve them.
And no my PC is not slow.

Answer (score 0):

I share my answer for Android studio 4.2:
I had to delete folder `C:\Users\Username\.gradle\caches`

Answer (score 0):

just go to gradle-wrapper.properties and update version gradle...zip

my version is gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

and restart android studio

Comment: This is not worked

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate Caches / Restart worked for me.

==> Go to File Menu on top left corner of android studio
==> Select Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue when doing my project.
I tried everything:
Delete every folders if I can;
Un-install;
Reset to default (I actually search SO for this);
Invalidate Cache;
Create a very new project for test;
Etc... All of those have no resolve problem

Now I have a final way to do: use **Intellji** instead of **Android Studio** and I am very happy now. This is advice for anyone who suffered by this issue

Answer (score 0):

use this lib
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
and Do invalidating Caches and restarting.

Answer (score 0):

the `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'` need `compileSdk 33` just change ktx to `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.2` and sdk version to `compileSdk 33` .
this worked for me.
GL

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was renaming $USERDIR/.AndroidStudio3.3/system folder and restarting AS.