# Android studio xml Editor Auto Complete is not working

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete, android-custom-view

[image: custom view]

title = description

xml editor auto complete not working in My CustomView.

but other views in working.

[image: normal view]

i tried invalid caches / restart .. but still not working

what should i do?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few tricks :

1.Clean and Run

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart
```

2.Turned off Power Save

```
File -> Power Save Mode
```

3. Delete `.idea` folder and all `.iml` and rebuild.

4.If this still didn't do the work,try changing your custom view's name to its original android view temporarily and use autocomplete inside, and then revert the view to its custom name.

Comment: Also see [Nisha's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38130891/5588347).

Comment: not working.. thanks for help