# XML editor auto completion, auto suggestion stopped working Android studio

Tags: android-studio, xml-editor

To make it work, I have already implemented below suggestions

Few tricks :

1.Clean and Run

File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Select Invalidate and Restart

2.Turned off Power Save

File -> Power Save Mode

3. Delete .idea folder and all .iml and rebuild.

I have uninstalled android studio and re-installed it. 
None of above worked for me.

I don't understand what to do now?
Kindly suggest me resolution of above issue.
Thanks..

Comment: try to explore this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries