# Android Studio, Xml autocomplete not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

I manually modified on build.gradle file. I made minSdkVersion from 21 to 14. Then I made 21 again by manually because of errors I received. After this process, autocomplete does not work in xml editor. 
I tried invalid caches and restart and delete .idea folder . But it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have power saving options enabled?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. Problem only in xml editor. @TaseerAhmad

Comment: [Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207367/9968399).

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio Go to C:\Users\UserName.android and rename the folder:

build-cache to build-cache_old
Go to C:\Users\UserName.AndroidStudio3.2\system and rename these folders:

caches to caches_old

compiler to compiler_old

compile-server to compile-server_old

conversion to conversion_old

external_build_system to external_build_system_old

frameworks to frameworks_old

gradle to gradle_old

resource_folder_cache to resource_folder_cache_old

Open the Android Studio and open your project again.

Answer (score 1):

## Compile/Target SDK 33 (2022)

If you're facing this problem with SDK 33, lower your sdk to 32, That fixed my problem

1. Go to your **build.gradle** file (Module)
2. Change your **compileSdk** to 32
3. Change your **targetSdk** to 32
4. Sync & Rebuild

Your gradle file should look like this

```
android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.package.name"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}
}
```

That should fix your issue

Comment: When I reduce compile SDK from 33 to 32 its worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply in your project

- Delete your **.idea** folder.
- Delete all **.iml** files.
- Then invalidate caches and restart..To do that:
- Go to **File** -> **Invalidate Caches/Restart** -> **Invalidate**
- Then finally Rebuild project....

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

These following steps are working for me:

1. Close android studio
2. Go to path/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/ delete caches folder
3. Start android studio