# Android studio 3.4.2 unresolved reference android.os.Bundle

Tags: android, kotlin

When I create a new android project in android studio 3.4.2, the gradle build without error and runs successfully. But Android Studio shows 4 errors.

1. Unresolved reference android.os.Bundle
2. onCreate 'overrides' nothing
3. super.onCreate , Cannot access class 'android.os.Bundle'. Check your
   module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

[image: Error image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IDE autocomplete in xml files is not working too, so when I scour SO, I got one link that solves my problems. Here is the link [Android Studio - XML Editor autocomplete not working with support libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by following these steps:

1. Delete the .idea folder
2. File -> Invalidate caches and restart.

Comment: Always the best solution for any kind of unexpected error in Android Studio :)