# Android Kotlin Suggestions Not Showing in XML

Tags: android, kotlin

when i am going to design the activity_mail.xml i just change the layout type as LinearLayout but i cannot write anything i created to look like this i cannot write the android:layout_width height inside the EditText why i don't

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't understand your question. Please clear

Comment: i edited above sir. i put the EditText inside EditText  the  i didn't write anything else. why

Comment: i cannot write the android:layout_width height inside the EditText why i don't

Comment: But I can, Check answer and let me know

Comment: if i type first two letter properties should properties displayed not displayed

Comment: what does this have to do with kotlin ?

Comment: Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: sir my problem is if i type layout the properties not displayed not working

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

 <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Gradle (click elephant icon) or File -> Inviladate Cache/Restart