# Why Android Studio no longer displays hints when writing code?

Tags: android-studio

I speak of the simple tips that you all know while writing the code, for example, it is enough to write in `XML`, `"ma..."` to receive the suggestion `"match_parent"` etc
How is it possible that they disappeared?

UPDATE:
I would like to specify that this problem mostly happens with 'XML. For example, before I just had to write WID and I got android: layout_width, now I have to write everything.

Comment: Which version of AS?

Comment: Android Studio Version 3.6.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - XML Editor autocomplete not working with support libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Auto complete and other features not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/11683)

Answer (score 0):

solution 1:

check if Power Save Mode on File menu is disabled.

Go File > Power Save mode

solution 2:

Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart