# Auto completion not work in my Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

When I press `ctrl + space` in the project I work it open dialog with just style, tools:target APi suggestion,
and no more suggestion I can find?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbBsH.jpg)

I tested with new project and it worked well with auto completion!
How I can fix this project?
also I sea other question here but non of them helped me?
thanks

Comment: Have you tried to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: are you reset setting  android studio??

Comment: I solved the problem with this solution: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54304838/3605630)