# How does the Android Studio autocomplete works in RecyclerView's `app:layoutManager`?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a custom view where I'm able to receive the path of the class by an attribute and create it in runtime and **I want it to work like the `app:layoutManager` in `RecyclerView`, if you try to add the path of your class, Android Studio shows the autocomplete and even the `.` works.**. How??

[image: android studio autocomplete]

**It's not a question about adding attributes**, I already had a look the [RecyclerView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-main/recyclerview/recyclerview/src/main/java/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.java) code and it is receiving a `string` and then, the string is used to create the instance in runtime.

[image]

[image]

I would be really thankful if someone can help me with this.

Comment: My best guess is that this feature is tied into the IDE itself. But I don't have any source for this guess.

Comment: I didn't find the solution but take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207367/5422725 discussion and other answers. I think @Joao is right. This feature is tied with IDE.

Answer (score 0):

- I think it depends on the IDE and the best answer that i can give you is that it searches throw the children of the top class.
- For example androidx is the top class so it will search throw it's children, then recyclerview and it will go throw it like this.
- I'm not sure but i think it's using some kind of decision tree algorithm
  and you can see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#tag_names_completion) for more information.