# Where's the caches folder for android studio 4.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Looking for the cache folder to delete it and re-index my project following [Android Studio - XML Editor autocomplete not working with support libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30684613/android-studio-xml-editor-autocomplete-not-working-with-support-libraries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio4.2

Answer (score 2):

In Linux it is found under:

/home/(user)/.cache/Google/AndroidStudio4.2