# How to get auto-complete working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, autocomplete

I am facing problem with Android Studio it's Auto complete in XML files not working.

I have tried all the option from already asked question like :-

> 1. Turn off Power save mode
> 2. Tick -> Editor->Code Completion
> 3. Invalidate cache.

Also tried all the accepted solution form already asked question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/1562659), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27629726/1562659), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18370599/1562659) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32153842/1562659).

But still unable to resolve the problem.

Comment: Try to update new version of android studio.

Comment: I am already using the latest version 2.1.2.

Comment: try this one Setting > Editor >General > Auto Import

Comment: the option is already on

Comment: check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31207367/2826147)

Comment: @Amit thanks but still have same issue might be some problem with android studio as I already knows these solution and tried but unable to resolve.

Comment: it should not be, as it is working for all other Android Studio 2.1.2 users

Comment: yes you are right but there might be chances of some error occured or my studio got crrupt  its better for me reinstall the fresh version